# UITextView - Begin Editing With All Text Selected In UITableViewCell()

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, uitextviewdelegate

I have a tableView with an object `TaskCell` which is a subclass of `UITableViewCell`

The `textView` is in the `TaskCell` and everything works fine except I can not get this line of code to select all text in the text view so the user can immediately overwrite the text if they so desire. Just as if you were to tap "select all" after holding onto the tap of the text.

```
textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.endOfDocument)
```

_

```
// All code relating to textView
class TaskCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView! { didSet { initTextView() } }

  fileprivate func initTextView() {
    textView.delegate = self
  }
}

extension TaskCell: UITextViewDelegate {
  func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    textView.selectedTextRange = textView.textRange(from: textView.beginningOfDocument, to: textView.endOfDocument)
  }
}


// class ListViewController: ViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! TaskCell

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two options :

```
 [yourtextView selectAll:nil];        //highlights text
 [yourtextView selectAll:self];       //highlights text and shows menu(cut copy paste)
```

in your case this will solve it :

```
- (BOOL)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [textView selectAll:nil];
  });
  return YES;
}
```

**Swift 3.0**

```
func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        textView.selectAll(nil)
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: it worked simply with me you should apply it in the situation you have 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGdSf.png

Comment: it works for example in textViewDidChange, as soon as I type something it highlights all text. but just not in textViewDidBeginEditing.

Comment: The DispatchQueue.main.async fixed it! in the case where it was shouldBeginEditing, it was causing some weird infinite loop bug on textViewDidEndEditing.

Comment: Thanks Again @Alsh compiler